# How can I make inline images bigger by default?

Tags: images

I'm a new emacs user (spacemacs, really, switched from Vim), and I'm having difficulty configuring emacs on my HiDPI display. Basically, I'm suffering from [this bug](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/8770). The problem is that, while I can scale the font size on emacs fine, graphics and images don't scale. That's most apparent in inline images, say, in org mode, EIN, or anything that displays an image. Is there a way to just make all images twice as big, by default?

Answer (score 2):

I'm far from being an expert on this, but would setting this variable help?

```
(setq org-image-actual-width SIZE_IN_PIXELS)
```

Comment: My version of org-mode doesn't have this variable, what does it do? Regardless, this wouldn't help outside Org mode.

Comment: Setting that variable doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: The variable is org-image-actual-width, not org-mode-actual-width. I submitted an edit.

Comment: I'd suggest trying this with emacs-26, which has a number of improvements in scaling support (although inline images might not be one of them).